# Displaying images in GitHub documentation

Tags: github

I have a [GitHub repository](http://github.com/MikeWarren2014/GroupManagementAppServer), for which I have created a [Wiki](https://github.com/MikeWarren2014/GroupManagementAppServer/wiki). In said Wiki, there are multiple pages, like [this one](https://github.com/MikeWarren2014/GroupManagementAppServer/wiki/Getting-Started) that I tried putting images on. For some reason, those images aren't showing up.

My Markdown code to the page that I have pointed out looks like this :

````
# Getting started
* [Using protoype](#using-prototype)
* [Working on code](#working-on-code)
 * [Installation instructions](#installation-instructions)
 * [Front-end code](#front-end-code)
 * [Back-end code](#back-end-code)
 * [Database code](#database-code)

### Using prototype

1. Go [here](https://mikewarren.me/YALApp/test.html) for the prototype. It will take you to the login page, which should look like this: ![if you see this, it means you probably need to right-click this to open the image in a new tab](../blob/master/loginPage.png)
2. Click on blue bar labelled "Login" to select a sample profile.
3. Log in.

### Working on code

Comes in multiple parts: the installation instructions and the different layers of code. These are discussed below. When discussing the directories these are in, I shall use ~ to symbolize project root directory.

##### Installation instructions

This project is written in node.js and has a `package.json` file at ```~/home/ec2-user/GroupManagementAppServer```. You should be able to ```npm link``` the dependencies the project needs. The database connection is to a MySQL database, so I would recommend a MySQL database management system (I personally use phpMyAdmin) unless you plan on changing that to another (say, MongoDB to keep in the node.js spirit of things).

##### Front-end code

This can be accessed at ```~/var/www/html/YALApp```. JavaScript dependencies that are third-party libraries are one directory up from that. 

##### Back-end code

This is written in JavaScript, and can be accessed at ```~/home/ec2-user/GroupManagementAppServer```. Main file is `appServer.js`, and if you are intending to use SSL/TLS, you will have to spell out the pathnames of `privateKey`, `certificate`, and/or `intermediate`. The application uses port number `8080`, and `8443` for https. 

##### Database code

I don't have anything connected to the database yet, and thus had no real need to include the script here, but when I do, it will probably be in either ```~``` or ```~/home/ec2-user/GroupManagementAppServer/data```.
````

I don't know how else to link to the image, which can be found in the repository, besides `../blob/master/[pathToImage]`. How to resolve this?

Comment: Also, should I be putting all documentation information, including pages, in one directory in that repository? It kinda feels appropriate to put it in the main directory of the code being documented

Comment: Yes, isolating the doc in its doc folder is also a practice seen in GitHub pages for instance: see https://github.com/blog/2228-simpler-github-pages-publishing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try and specify the full url of your repo instead of a relative path.

See "[Linking to images in a repository](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-images-to-wikis/#linking-to-images-in-a-repository)"

> You can link to an image in a repository on GitHub by copying the URL in your browser and using that as the path to the image.
>   For example, embedding an image in your wiki using Markdown might look like this:

```
[[https://github.com/username/repository/blob/master/img/octocat.png|alt=octocat]]
```

Comment: I agree, but this is what is currently and officially documented.